# Uncaught TypeError: jsonpCallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

H iam implementing jsonp ajax function to execute but i get Uncaught TypeError: jsonpCallback is not a function .what seems to be problem

```
APP_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
 $.ajax({
       url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/d..er/lang-api/?callback=jsonpCallback", 
       method: "GET", 
       data:{drop_lang:drop_language},
       dataType: "jsonp", 
      jsonp: !1, 
      jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback"
}), 
 window.jsonpCallback = function (e) {
        e.fn.surveywidget = function (a) {
```

Comment: format your code first

Comment: ok,i am passing callback to my django function

Comment: and the view returns data but the function window.jsonpCallback is not recognised

Comment: nevermind my previous comment - didn't notice the `jsonp: !1`

Comment: The code you posted is not the entire code is it? it looks odd with the commas where they are

Comment: no not the full code

Comment: e.fn.surveywidget = function (a) {
        return
       ...
    }
}(jQuery);

Comment: still don't like the commas on line 1 and 9

Comment: no the commas are not a problem

Comment: $.ajax({url:   "..p/?callback=jsonpCallback", method: "GET", data: {e...age}, dataType: "jsonp", jsonp: !1, jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback"}), window.jsonpCallback = function (e)
 {       used at another location works

Comment: disregard my previous comment, maybe

Comment: Why go thru the effort of callback handling? let jquery do that for you, don't pass any callback in the url and jquery will internally use and provide you response in `success` function or `done` function whichever you like

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that there is a function named `jsonpCallback` defined on the site you submit your data to: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/d..er/lang-api"